# Whats the equivalent of ES6 methods(class) in es5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

How would we polyfill es6 class methods into ES5?

I am reading a book and it says the following:

```
class Ninja {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    swingSword() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

is the same as

```
function Ninja(name) {
    this.name = name;
} 

Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function() {
    return true;
};
```

I am just asking why are we adding the swingSword on the prototype and not inside the constructor function?

Because the function should be on the object and not on the prototype chain.

Am i right or wrong?

Comment: You are wrong, the book is right.

Comment: Book is right. Let's elaborate.
function Ninja(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Creates a function object - Function{name: 'value you're passing while calling the function'}
And for each time you call this, this function object will be created and stored in memory for use.
Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function() {
    return true;
};
Whereas swingSword function will sit on the prototype and only have one reference in memory and all func objects will point to this memory address.

Same is achieved by the class you've mentioned. Hope my explanation helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be on the prototype, methods are not per-instance data. Can't think of any language that implements it that way, the whole idea of classes is to have a whole class of objects that have the same set of methods.

If it was put it inside the constructor function, it would be a unique function per instance made with the constructor. e.g, 1000 objects == 1000 functions, per "method".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I get it.

Comment: In reality, even if you attach the function in the constructor, you won't end up with 1000 functions per 1000 instances. You end up with 1000 closures, and 1 function. Closures should be very optimized, so it is nowhere near as expensive as creating 1000 different functions. Also, for VERY time critical methods, they may be faster to run (at the cost of slower object creation), since the Javascript engine will first check at this.func, then at Object.getPrototypeOf(this).func (and so on). But yes, prototype is generally best, and lower maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the function to just the object would only work for a `Ninja`.  To create a class that extends `Ninja`, for example `Kunoichi`, you would normally copy the `Ninja` prototype.  Unfortunately, because `swingSword` is not in the prototype, your `Kunoichi` cannot swing swords.

You must add the function in prototype to allow the class to be extended.

Answer (score 0):

If we add a method to the prototype, only one instance of that method exists in memory, and it’s shared between all objects created from the constructor.

If we add the swingSword method directly to the Ninja constructor function, then every object would have its own copy of that method, taking up more memory.

Answer (score -5):

---

```
var $class = function ($superclass, config) {
    // All classes have a superclass with the root 
    // of this $class hierarchy being Object.
    var self = function (config) {
        // Object.assign or $.extend or ...
        config && Object.assign(this, config);
    };
    self.prototype = new $superclass(config);
    return self;
};

var A = $class(Object, {
    sayWhat: "Hello, I'm an A",
    say: function () {
        console.log(this.sayWhat);
    }
});

var B = $class(A, {
    sayWhat: "Hello, I'm a B"
});

var C = $class(B, {
    say: function () {
        console.log("C SAYS: " + this.sayWhat);
    },
    superSay: function () {
        // how to call a superclass method
        B.prototype.say.call(this);
    }
});

var a = new A();
a.say();  // Hello, I'm an A

var b = new B();
b.say();  // Hello, I'm a B

var c = new C();
c.say();  // C SAYS: Hello, I'm a B

// create a "one-off" object
var d = new C({
    sayWhat: "I'm special!",
    say: function () {
        console.log("hey!");
    }
});
d.say();  // hey!
d.superSay();  // I'm special!
C.prototype.say.call(d);  // C SAYS: I'm special!
```

---

Comment: How does this block of code answer the question? Take a look at [answer] for how to write a useful answer. Don't just post a code dump; you should include some text explaining what your code does and how it answers the question.